# Android wear Xamarin Messages

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to send Messages from an Android Wear Device to the connected Phone. 
The Android Smartphone Application is written in native Java and working. The Wear-Application is written in c# with Xamarin and not working. 
Here is what I got so far:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, IMessageApiMessageListener,
     IGoogleApiClientConnectionCallbacks, IResultCallback
{
    private IGoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private SensorManager _SensorManager;

    private Sensor _Gyroscop;
    private static  String WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH = "//message";
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {   
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        var v = FindViewById<WatchViewStub> (Resource.Id.watch_view_stub);
        v.LayoutInflated += delegate {
        };

        if(_SensorManager == null) {
            _SensorManager = (SensorManager)GetSystemService(SensorService);
        }

        SensorListener s = new SensorListener(); 
        _Gyroscop = _SensorManager.GetDefaultSensor (SensorType.Gyroscope);
        _SensorManager.RegisterListener (s, _Gyroscop,SensorDelay.Normal);
        s.SensorChangedEvent +=  delegate(SensorEvent e) {
            if(mApiClient.IsConnected ){
                sendMessage(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH,"Test");
            }
        };
        initGoogleApiClient ();
    }

    private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClientBuilder( this )
                .AddApi( WearableClass.Api )
                .AddConnectionCallbacks( this )
                .Build();

    if (mApiClient != null && !(mApiClient.IsConnected || mApiClient.IsConnecting)) {
        mApiClient.Connect ();
        }
    }



    private void sendMessage(  String path,  String text ) {
        WearableClass.NodeApi
                     .GetConnectedNodes (mApiClient)
                     .SetResultCallback (this);
    }

    public void OnResult (Java.Lang.Object raw)
    {
        Exception nodeException, messageException;
        try {
            //send the message
            var nodeResult = raw.JavaCast<INodeApiGetConnectedNodesResult> ();
            foreach (var node in nodeResult.Nodes)
            WearableClass.MessageApi.SendMessage (mApiClient, node.Id, WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, StringToByteArray("Test")).SetResultCallback (this); //will go to second try/catch block
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            nodeException = e;
        }
        try {
            //check that it worked correctly
            var messageResult = raw.JavaCast<IMessageApiSendMessageResult> ();
            if (!messageResult.Status.IsSuccess)                    
                Console.WriteLine ("Problem");
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            messageException = e;
        }
    }

    public void OnConnected (Bundle p0)
    {
        WearableClass.MessageApi.AddListener (mApiClient, this);
    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended (int p0)
    {
        WearableClass.MessageApi.RemoveListener (mApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

The Problem is that the phone dose not receive the Message.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I'm struggling with sending messages (or data) from handheld to wear (or vice versa). When sending, the *receiving* app crashes immediately. I primarily used these two references: http://android-wear-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sync.html#first-wearable-message and http://toastdroid.com/2014/08/18/messageapi-simple-conversations-with-android-wear/

Comment: I have the Sending problem with Mono for Android not jet solve. I am had switched to native Java and this seams to work with no trouble. I ues this tutorial: http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-guide-to-the-android-wear-message-api/152[link]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally finished to implement a minimum working example demonstrating the communication between handheld and wear. It is a pure Xamarin solution and allows to send messages as well as data maps in both directions.

Since sending and receiving information works the same way for handhelds and wears, I created a shared project called "Communication". It contains a "Communicator" class, which is used by both applications.

Furthermore, the AXML and C# implementation of both main activities is identical in this simple example. We will see two buttons on each device allowing to send either a new message or some data.

## The Communicator

The `Communicator` class derives from `Java.Lang.Object` and implements two listener interfaces.

```
public class Communicator: Java.Lang.Object, IMessageApiMessageListener, IDataApiDataListener
{
    ...
```

It contains a `IGoogleApiClient`

```
    readonly IGoogleApiClient client;
```

and stores a common path:

```
    const string path = "/communicator";
```

(Both APIs, the message API and the data API, require a "path" as a kind of communication channel identifier. Using the same path for all messages is a first attempt, but might get noisy when increasing the traffic in a more complex app.)

The `Communicator` is constructed using an Android `Context` and builds the `IGoogleApiClient`.

```
    public Communicator(Context context)
    {
        client = new GoogleApiClientBuilder(context)
            .AddApi(WearableClass.Api)
            .Build();
    }
```

The following methods will be called when resuming or pausing an activity. They connect or disconnect the `client` and register or unregister the `Communicator` as a message/data listener:

```
    public void Resume()
    {
        if (!client.IsConnected) {
            client.Connect();
            WearableClass.MessageApi.AddListener(client, this);
            WearableClass.DataApi.AddListener(client, this);
        }
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        if (client != null && client.IsConnected) {
            client.Disconnect();
            WearableClass.MessageApi.RemoveListener(client, this);
            WearableClass.DataApi.RemoveListener(client, this);
        }
    }
```

There are two rather similar methods for sending information, one for messages and one for data maps. To avoid blocking the UI, both tasks are performed on a background thread. Note that messages are sent to specific "nodes" (= devices), while data has no specific receiver.

```
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Task.Run(() => {
            foreach (var node in Nodes()) {
                var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
                var result = WearableClass.MessageApi.SendMessage(client, node.Id, path, bytes).Await();
                var success = result.JavaCast<IMessageApiSendMessageResult>().Status.IsSuccess ? "Ok." : "Failed!";
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Communicator: Sending message {0}... {1}", message, success));
            }
        });
    }

    public void SendData(DataMap dataMap)
    {
        Task.Run(() => {
            var request = PutDataMapRequest.Create(path);
            request.DataMap.PutAll(dataMap);
            var result = WearableClass.DataApi.PutDataItem(client, request.AsPutDataRequest()).Await();
            var success = result.JavaCast<IDataApiDataItemResult>().Status.IsSuccess ? "Ok." : "Failed!";
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Communicator: Sending data map {0}... {1}", dataMap, success));
        });
    }
```

Of course, we need methods for receiving data. They are actually defined by the two interfaces above and need to get implemented. (`OnDataChanged` checks for the correct path, since the data *might* not be dedicated to this app.)

```
    public void OnMessageReceived(IMessageEvent messageEvent)
    {
        var message = Encoding.Default.GetString(messageEvent.GetData());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Communicator: Message received \"{0}\"", message));
        MessageReceived(message);
    }

    public void OnDataChanged(DataEventBuffer p0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Communicator: Data changed ({0} data events)", p0.Count));
        for (var i = 0; i < p0.Count; i++) {
            var dataEvent = p0.Get(i).JavaCast<IDataEvent>();
            if (dataEvent.Type == DataEvent.TypeChanged && dataEvent.DataItem.Uri.Path == path)
                DataReceived(DataMapItem.FromDataItem(dataEvent.DataItem).DataMap);
        }
    }
```

Each of them calls one of the following events.

```
    public event Action<string> MessageReceived = delegate {};

    public event Action<DataMap> DataReceived = delegate {};
```

Last but not least, we need a method for retrieving all connected nodes:

```
    IList<INode> Nodes()
    {
        var result = WearableClass.NodeApi.GetConnectedNodes(client).Await();
        return result.JavaCast<INodeApiGetConnectedNodesResult>().Nodes;
    }
```

## The layout

For simplicity, both apps use the same layout. It contains two buttons, each with 50 % of the total screen size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/messageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Send message" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dataButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Send data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## The main activity

Both apps implement a `MainActivity` derived from `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ...
```

Each activity has a `communicator` encapsulating all communication related code.

```
    Communicator communicator;
```

At the end of `OnCreate` we instantiate the `communicator`,

```
        communicator = new Communicator(this);
```

and wire both the `messageButton`

```
        var messageButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.messageButton);
        messageButton.Click += (sender, e) => communicator.SendMessage("time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));
        communicator.MessageReceived += message => RunOnUiThread(() => messageButton.Text = message);
```

as well as the `dataButton`

```
        var dataButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dataButton);
        dataButton.Click += delegate {
            var dataMap = new DataMap();
            dataMap.PutString("time", DateTime.Now.ToString("T"));
            communicator.SendData(dataMap);
        };
        communicator.DataReceived += dataMap => RunOnUiThread(() => dataButton.Text = dataMap.ToString());
```

(We generate the "long time" string including seconds using the format identifier "T". This way the string will change from one click to another in most cases. This is important, since sending the same *data map* twice does not trigger the `OnDataChanged` event handler!)

Finally, we `Resume` and `Pause` the `communicator` at the right place:

```
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        communicator.Resume();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        communicator.Pause();

        base.OnPause();
    }
```

## The manifest

Since we are using the Google Mobile Services, we need to put the following line into the `<application>` tag of both `AndroidManifest.xml` files:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

## The result

When opening the apps, we see the following screens.

[image]
[image]

After a few clicks, both apps sent the current time to each other, either via the message API or the data API. Now the screens look as follows.

[image]
[image]

Note that the sender of some data map will receive it as well. Therefore, the time on the `dataButton` is the same on both devices. In contrast, a message is only sent to all *other* nodes, thus does not return to the sender.

Comment: Any updates to this project, looking to implement something similar?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I finally find my bug and the reason why they do not communicate. The problem was that both applications had different package names (you can set them in the AndroidManifest.xml). After setting them to an equal name the communication works. Thank you Falko for your great help :) .